# different token for different mobile devices using FOSOAuthBundle

Tags: symfony

I have build up an iphone app for my website, for which I did the authentication part using FOSOAuth Bundle and generated access tokens for individual users..

But for now I am trying to generate the access token for device specific e.g. iphone, ipad and so on..

If this becomes possible to do please suggest me some ways how to initiate...

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly a Symfony question but rather on OAuth. But to get to the point: if you need separate token for each user and each device, create a client for each app or device. You can read more on this great blog post: http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/